# Как убрать горизонтальный скроллбар на сайте?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Добрый день всем!

Стоит задача сделать резиновый сайт, максимальная ширина  – 1280px, минимальная –  1024 (при разрешении 1024px не должно быть горизонтального  скроллбара). Можно ли как-нибудь решить эту проблему, не меняя `min-width:1024px` на меньше?

Comment: В коде 1024px, а в реальности 1024px + 17px вертикального бегунка. В этом проблема?

Comment: я извиняюсь, но @cypher ты пишешь бред! какие к черту +17px???

Comment: Вертикальный скроллбар браузера занимает порядка 17px в ширину. Зависит это, конечно, от операционки и браузера. Если ты вытсаляешь ширину, или минимальную ширину в 1024px, то на дисплее шириной в 1024px из-за этого вертикального скролла появится и горизонтальный. Я не прав?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сайты никогда не верстают под четкое разрешение экрана

Допустим если **1024px*768px** то тут явно не 1024 нужно делать а меньше, ибо 1024 это полное разрешение экрана, а браузер занимает тоже часть ширины по этому и верстка должна быть немного меньше допустим **960px.**

+ смотрим ответ [[@thunder](/users/9040/thunder)](/users/9040/thunder) что тоже возможно как вариант

Comment: полностью согласен.

Comment: Шрек прав :). К примеру, в старых версиях оперы часть функционала браузера выносилась в вертикальное меню, пикселей в 70, прижатое к лвому краю. Это существенный кусок ширины. Сейчас это меню вроде вынесли как в большинстве браузеров, но думаю, что есть настройка возвращающая колонный вид. Так же пользователи иногда делают нижние панели системы (с пуском, квикланчем, треем и т.д.) сбоку. Еще вертикальный бегунок который я упоминал.

Comment: А 960px это самый популярный вариант еще и потому, что это размер модульной сетки, пришедшей из типографии в вебдизайн: http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/the-960-grid-system-made-easy/ Но это в первую очередь, конечно, к дизайнерам.

Comment: Все предельно ясно, огромное спасибо за помощь. Теперь буду знать.

Answer (score 2):

Это значит, что какой-то элемент вылезает за границы экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте overflow-x: hidden;
А вообще это ошибки в верстке, но если не хочется их искать иногда помогает этот метод.

Comment: ....что есть не правильно))) в смысле "не искать, а забить" на ошибки))) так ничему не научишься и будет продолжать их делать

Comment: абсолютно согласен, но некоторых это устраивает ;)

Comment: и не поспоришь ;)